# How to fix history.push in all .js file?

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a router in App.js file.
I'm creating a login page and I change page with this.props.history.push('/homepage') to go to the homepage. It works.

Now I'm in /homepage and i would like to do the same but it don't works ...
I make: this.context.history.push('/test'); and I've got an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".

I already tried to use "this.context.router.history.push('/page');" but i have the same error. I tried to use browserHistory instead of HashRouter but it don't works.
The only thing who work is to create functions and to call them with the buttonclick. But i can't do it with the react way !

```
Include App.js:

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './dashboard/Dashboard';
import Register from "./login/Register"
import Login from "./login/Login"
import Admin from "./admin/Admin"

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router basename="/">
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Login}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/homepage" component={HomePage}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/register" component={Register}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/admin" component={Admin}>
                    </Route>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;





Include Login file

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Link, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import O2Connexion from './O2Connexion'
import "../App.css"
import Axios from 'axios'
import AreaLogo from '../ressources/arealogo.png'

class Login extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            test: ''
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        let target = e.target;
        let value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        let name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            this.props.history.push('/homepage')
        }
    }

    render() {
         ...




Include NavBar file

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Layout, Header, Navigation, Content } from 'react-mdl';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.test = this.test.bind(this);
    }

    test(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //ne marche pas comme ça
        this.context.history.push('/homepage');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{height: '300px', position: 'relative'}}>
                <Layout fixedHeader>
                    <Header title={<span><span style={{ color: '#ddd' }}>Area</span></span>}>
                        <Navigation>
                            <a onClick={this.test}>Home Page</a>
                            <a>Admin</a>
                            <a>Log out</a>
                        </Navigation>
                    </Header>
                    <Content />
                </Layout>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

So it don't works on the navabar file and i have no idea why

Can someone explain me why it don't works and if it exist a "reactjs" way to do it ? Thank you and have a nice evenning

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap your components with **withRouter** hoc like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';

class Navbar extends Component { ... }
const NavbarWithRouter = withRouter(Navbar);

export default NavbarWithRouter;
```

Doing this way you could access **match**, **location**, **history** inside **Navbar**'s component *props*

You need to repeat steps above for each component where you need access for seeking properties

Comment: Thanks but what should i do with the var NavbarWithRouter ?

Comment: Well, you could end up with `export default withRouter(Navbar);` and it should work as-well.
But, I would recommend to use a intermediate variable because it can be helpful when you use debuggers, you could distinguish wrapped/unwrapped components